# Background Task in FastAPI is not working properly

Tags: python, asynchronous, fastapi, background-task

I am performing predictions with FastAPI, using background tasks. Everything seems to be working, but if I warp the background task function in another function and call it then it's not working. Why is this happening? Don't background tasks in FastAPI work when i pass the function this way?

```py
# this is the working example
@app.get(api_names[0])
async def predict(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks,solute,solvent):
    background_tasks.add_task(predictions,solute,solvent)
    return {'success'}
```

```py
# but when i change the above end point to below its not working
@app.get(api_names[0])
async def predict(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks,solute,solvent):
    sample = predict_dup(0)
    background_tasks.add_task(sample,solute,solvent)
    return {'success'}

async def predict_dup(task_id):
    if task_id == 0:
        return predictions
    elif task_id == 2:
        return predictions_two
```

Comment: What exactly does "is not working" mean? What is the expected output and what is happening?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: From your example there isn't a real difference between the two, so attach your debugger and see what's actually happening, or create an example that people can run to see that it actually works/doesn't work (your function isn't wrapped, it's just referenced under a different name).

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/#add-the-background-task), `.add_task()`, receives a task function to be run in the background, along with any arguments that should be passed to the task function. In your case, one way to return a function from another function to pass it to the background tasks would be to use the [`partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) method from [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) that returns "a new partial object which when called will behave like *func*". Hence, you could use as follows:

```
from functools import partial
return partial(predictions)
return partial(predictions_two)
```

Alternatively, you could have a dictionary that keeps the functions with their corresponding task ids, and use it to look up for a function based on a given id. Example below:

```
functions = {0: predictions, 1: predictions_two}
...
async def predict(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks,...
      background_tasks.add_task(functions[task_id], <ADD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENTS_HERE>)
```

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76280152/17865804) for more details on Background Tasks.