# How to use Background Tasks inside a function that is called by a FastAPI endpoint?

Tags: python, fastapi, background-task, starlette

I have the below FastAPI endpoint:

```
@app.post("/abcd", response_model=abcdResponseModel)
async def getServerDetails(IncomingData: serverModel) -> abcdResponseModel:
    """
    Get Server Details
    """
    result = ServerDetails(IncomingData.dict())
    return result
```

The above is calling the function below

```
def ServerDetails(IncomingData: dict) -> Tuple[list, int]:
    background_tasks = BackgroundTasks()
    background_tasks.add(notification_func, arg1, arg2)
    response = some operation.....
    return response, 500
```

Is this the way to do this, or do I need to create a `BackgroundTasks()` object inside `getServerDetails` endpoitn and pass it to  the `ServerDetails` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`BackgroundTasks`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/#background-tasks) work once you define a parameter in your endpoint with a type declaration of `BackgroundTasks`, which will then be added to the returned `Response` object by FastAPI. Just creating an instance of it inside your custom function or endpoint, e.g., `tasks = BackgroundTasks()`, it wouldn't work as expected, unless you added  `tasks` to the `Response` object on your own (this option is demostrated below as well).

Hence, if you didn't want to add the tasks inside your endpoint, but rather inside a custom function that is called from within your endpoint, you would still need to define the parameter as mentioned above, and then pass it to your custom function.

Also, as per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/#technical-details):

> By only using `BackgroundTasks` (and not `BackgroundTask`), it's then
> possible to use it as a *path operation function* parameter and have
> FastAPI handle the rest for you, just like when using the `Request`
> object directly.
>
> It's still possible to use `BackgroundTask` alone in FastAPI, but
> **you have to create the object** in your code **and return a Starlette `Response` including it**.

### Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, BackgroundTasks

app = FastAPI()

def send_notification(message):
    print(f'Notification will be sent over. Message: {message}')


def add_some_tasks(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(send_notification, message="Success")
 
 
@app.get("/{msg}")
def send_msg(msg: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    add_some_tasks(background_tasks)
    return {"message": "Request has been successfully submitted."}
```

### Alternative Options

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73283272/17865804) and the documentation excerpt earlier, one could also add the background task(s) directly to the `Response` object in the following ways. Note that `JSONResponse` could also be replaced by any other type of class inheriting from `Response`, such as `PlainTextResponse`.

##### Option 1

```py
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks

@app.get("/{msg}")
def send_msg(msg: str):
    content = {"message": "Request has been successfully submitted."}
    tasks = BackgroundTasks()
    tasks.add_task(send_notification, message="Success")
    return JSONResponse(content, background=tasks)
```

Hence, to perform the above inside your custom function instead, you could follow the example below:

```py
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks

def add_some_tasks():
    tasks = BackgroundTasks()
    tasks.add_task(send_notification, message="Success")
    return tasks
    

@app.get("/{msg}")
def send_msg(msg: str):
    content = {"message": "Request has been successfully submitted."}
    tasks = add_some_tasks()
    return JSONResponse(content, background=tasks)
```

##### Option 2

Simply, a variation of the previous option.

```py
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

@app.get("/{msg}")
def send_msg(msg: str):
    content = {"message": "Request has been successfully submitted."}
    tasks = BackgroundTasks()
    tasks.add_task(send_notification, message="Success")
    response = JSONResponse(content)
    response.background = tasks
    return response
```

Again, if you need to add the tasks inside a separate function than the endpoint, please follow the example provided in Option 1.

Just for the sake of completeness, to add a single task only, you could alternatively use Starlette's `BackgroundTask` (this applies to both options provided above):

```py
from starlette.background import BackgroundTask

@app.get("/{msg}")
def send_msg(msg: str):
    # ...
    response.background = BackgroundTask(send_notification, message="Success")
    return response
```

### Side Note

Similar to API endpoints, FastAPI will run `async def` background tasks directly in the event loop, whereas background tasks defined with normal `def` will be run in a separate thread from an external threadpool that is then `await`ed, as such tasks/functions would otherwise block the event loop. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77941425/17865804) for more details on this concept that would help you decide whether you should define your background task(s) with `async def` or just `def`.

Comment: Is it a bad idea to use BackgroundTask within synchronous endpoints? Do I block other requests in this case?

Comment: @AlwaysJunior A `BackgroundTask` is executed after returning a response; hence, it has nothing to do with the endpoint itself. Now, if the background task function is defined with `async def`, it will run directly in the event loop, whereas FastAPI will run a normal `def` function in an external threadpool that is then `await`ed, instead of calling it directly, as it would block the event loop (same concept as API endpoints). Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77941425/17865804) for more details.