# How to send email with attachment in FastAPI using fastapi-mail library?

Tags: python, csv, email, fastapi, email-attachments

```
@app.post("/file")
async def send_file(
    background_tasks: BackgroundTasks,
    file: UploadFile = File(...),
    email:EmailStr = Form(...)
    ) -> JSONResponse:

    message = MessageSchema(
            subject="Fastapi mail module",
            recipients=[email],
            body="Simple background task",
            subtype=MessageType.html,
            attachments=[file])

    fm = FastMail(conf)

    background_tasks.add_task(fm.send_message,message)

    return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"message": "email has been sent"}
```

The above code was taken from [fastapi-mail](https://sabuhish.github.io/fastapi-mail/example/)'s documentation page.

**Requirement**

I don't have a file, I have file path from which I need to read contents and need to send a file (CSV, PDF, ...). How can I do that?

```
@app.post("/file")
async def send_file(
    background_tasks: BackgroundTasks,
    file_path: str,
    email: EmailStr
) -> JSONResponse:
    message = MessageSchema(
        subject="Fastapi mail module",
        recipients=[email],
        body="Simple background task",
        subtype=MessageType.html,
        attachments=[file_path])

    )
    message.attach(file_data, filename="")
    fm = FastMail(conf)
    background_tasks.add_task(fm.send_message, message)
    return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"message": "email has been sent"})
```

Comment: In the first example, `file` is a file object. Hence, in the second example, you might try opening the file (e.g., `file = open(file_path, 'rb')`) and pass it to `attachments`. You can then close the `file`, [using a background task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76280152/17865804) - if you would like to remove the file from disk as well, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804)

Answer (score 0):

attachments array is a tuple array like
attachments=[("filename", "filetype", file_data)]

where file_data is the result of file.read() in a opened file like Chris said

here is an example:

```py
@app.post("/file")
async def send_file(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, file_path: str, email: EmailStr) -> JSONResponse:
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        file_data = f.read()

    message = MessageSchema(
        subject="Fastapi mail module",
        recipients=[email],
        body="Simple background task",
        subtype="html",
        attachments=[("filename", "filetype", file_data)]
    )

    fm = FastMail(conf)
    background_tasks.add_task(fm.send_message, message)

    return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"message": "email has been sent"})
```

Comment: attachments=[("filename", "filetype", file_data)]
'attachments' this will accept only dict , str and UploadFile (File), tuple it will not accept.

Answer (score 0):

```
async def email(file_path:str):
    subject = ""
    content= ""
    message = MessageSchema(
        subject=subject,
        recipients=[],
        cc=[],
        body=content,
        subtype="html",
        attachments=[file_path],
    )
    fm = FastMail(conf)
    await fm.send_message(message)
    return {"success": True}
```

we can pass directly **file_path** as **str**

or

as **dict** need to read the **file** by opening and pass like this.

**attachments=[{"file": f"{file_path}", "content": file}]**

or

as **UploadFile** (not tried)

**response:**

attachment coming inside outlook item(need to work) but its working.