# Python Fast API BackgroundTask not working

Tags: python, fastapi, background-task

Do anyone had problem recently with Fast API BackgroundTask?

Name: fastapi
Version: 0.99.1

In the begin of the year I used and it was very fast to implement it. But now I tried everything and it runs like a normal function.

My code it was very long that cause I was reading multiple pdfs and doing the parser. So I tried with some basic example to test the core functionality but it didn't work still.

Examples that I tried:

--> First attempt (test)

--> Second attempt (test_asyncio) - I found someone talking about using asyncio

-router file

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, BackgroundTasks, Depends, status

from app.config.dbconfig import get_db
from app.services.pdf import ServicePdf
from app.utils.service_result import ServiceResult, handle_result

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/pdf",
    tags=["pdf"],
    responses={404: {"description": "Not found"}},
)


@router.post("/test", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def parse_candidate_pdf(
    background_tasks: BackgroundTasks,
    db: get_db = Depends(),
):
    background_tasks.add_task(ServicePdf(db).test, "name")
    return handle_result(ServiceResult(None), status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


@router.post("/test-asyncio", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def parse_candidate_pdf_asyncio(
    background_tasks: BackgroundTasks,
    db: get_db = Depends(),
):
    background_tasks.add_task(ServicePdf(db).test_asyncio, "name")
    return handle_result(ServiceResult(None), status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

-service file

```
import asyncio
import time

from app.services.main import AppService

class ServicePdf(AppService):
    def test(self, name):
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Awake now!", name)

    async def test_asyncio(self, name):
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print("Awake now!", name)
```

What is happening:

1. Enter on the route
2. Just return the response after run all that have inside of the task that was suppose to be in background.

What I expected:

1. Enter on the route
2. Return the response
3. Continue running the background task function on the background

Edit1: I created a new project, very basic only with the base logic and both functions worked! so it's not about the version

main.py

```
import time
import asyncio
from fastapi import FastAPI, BackgroundTasks

app = FastAPI()


async def process_data_asyncio(data: str):
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print(f"Processed data: {data}")


def process_data(data: str):
    time.sleep(5)
    print(f"Processed data: {data}")


@app.post("/process-data-asyncio/")
async def parse_asyncio(data: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(process_data_asyncio, data)
    return {"message": "Data processing started in the background."}


@app.post("/process-data/")
async def parse(data: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(process_data, data)
    return {"message": "Data processing started in the background."}


@app.get("/")
def home():
    return "api"
```

command to run:

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

Comment: Noone will be able to help you without enough code and version information to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: Ohh Soryy, is the first time that I created a question, thank you for the clarification!

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76280152/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873984/17865804) helpful

Comment: Thank you Chris! 2nd answer is very aligned with what I'm trying to do. Gave me new insights, unfortunately It is still not working

Answer (score 0):

After trying the edit1 code, I saw that the problem was not about the backgroundTask, it was about something else on my project, after so many tries I found the issue!

It had one custom middleware on main.py that is used to create logs, and this was making my backgroundTask work like a normal function:

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def custom_middleware_logging(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
response_body = [chunk async for chunk in response.body_iterator]
response.body_iterator = iterate_in_threadpool(iter(response_body))
    # logging logic...
return response
```

Changing to a BackgroundTask for running the logs made it work!

Solution:

```
    @app.middleware("http")
    async def custom_middleware_logging(request: Request, call_next):
        response = await call_next(request)
        response.background = BackgroundTask(write_log_data, request, response)
    return response
```

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804) helpful as well.